# Example with super function call in UVM

Tags: oop, system-verilog, uvm

I have come across this statement and I have used many testbench components with this prototype. super.run_phase(), super.build_phase, super.connect_phase.

Can anyone explain with a simple example why we need to call super functions everytime. I understand we need to construct parent before constructing the child but why do we have to call parent's connect_phase etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [UVM component source code](http://www.specman-verification.com/source_bank/uvm-1.1/src/base/uvm_component.svh.php), every phase is by **default an empty virtual function/task**:

```
function void uvm_component::connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
      connect();
      return; 
   endfunction
function void uvm_component::connect();             
  return; 
endfunction
```

It is **not mandatory** to call `super.connect_phase` or any phase from base test or base driver etc.

You might have instantiated environment in base test and henceforth calling `super.build_phase` shall create the required instances. Similarly, you might connected some ports-exports in base environment/agent and a call to `super.connect_phase` shall connect them.

But, `build_phase` is an exception to this. It is highly *recommended* to use **build_phase/connect_phase** for user defined code, instead of using any code in the constructor.

You can call `super.build_phase()`/`super.connect_phase()` in an extended class depending on the overriding requirement or add the the existing functionality in the base class `build_phase()`/`connect_phase()`.

You can't completely override a constructor because SystemVerilog requires that the extended class constructor call super.new().

A call to `super.build_phase()` is **mandatory in base class's** build_phase if the field automation macros are used.

For example:

```
class base_test extends uvm_test;
`uvm_component_utils(base_test)
//...
function build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
super.build_phase(phase); // for automatic configuration of fields
endfunction
//...
function connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
super.connect_phase(phase); // normal practice 
endfunction
endclass

class my_test extends base_test;
`uvm_component_utils(my_test)
//...
function build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
super.build_phase(phase); // for environment creation
endfunction
//...
function connect_phase(uvm_phase phase);
// super.connect_phase(phase); // will compile even if not call-ed
endfunction
endclass
```

From [UVM Class reference](https://www.vmmcentral.org/uvm_vmm_ik/files3/base/uvm_component-svh.html#uvm_component.build_phase):

> Any override should call super.build_phase(phase) to execute the
>   automatic configuration of fields registed in the component by calling
>   **apply_config_settings**.  To turn off automatic configuration for a
>   component, do not call super.build_phase(phase).

The `apply_config_settings` is used for applying configuration settings to each field of the class.

If you **do not** want `apply_config_settings` to be called for a component, then the `build_phase()` method should be overloaded and you apply_config_settings call `super.build_phase(phase)`.

Comment: Another important difference is calling super.new is not optional and must be the first statement in the constructor. In any other method, it is optional and does not need to be the first statement. This mean in the build_phase, you can provide factory or configuration overrides and then call super.build_phase().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Double checking my understanding here. If env wants to build a driver and env decides to change config settings of driver. In this case, driver's build_phase function calls super.build and this does config overrides for the driver as requested by the env. Is this correct?

Comment: It seems you are confused in **parent-child** and **base-extended** relationship. Env is parent of driver and base_driver (or uvm_driver) is base class for user_defined_driver. Calling `super.build_phase` from driver calls build_phase of base driver (or uvm_driver or whichever is the base class) not the build phase of env. The base driver applies config settings, the one which uvm registered fields may require.

Comment: I am still confused. Still, env is the one who creates the driver right? If super.build_phase calls uvm_driver class and build_phase of uvm_component calls apply_config_settings, What is the way for env to override default config of driver (assuming env wants to override driver config before building driver). Does it have to put that information in config_db?

Comment: Particularly, build_phase is top-down phase. So, when env calls super.build_phase, the base env (or uvm_env) build_phase gets executed. It applies all the default config settings. There after the user_defined_env's build_phase executes, in which some overrides/config_db's etc. are stored (information stored internally in UVM classes).

Comment: Again, after env's build_phase ends, the user_driver's build_phase starts which in-turn calls super.build_phase to execute build of base_driver (or uvm_driver). Now, the default settings of driver are applied and then user_driver's build_phase executes (getting config_db and other stuff). The user_driver, can again set some settings for it's child components.

Comment: So, all the UVM components call super.build_phase to apply all default settings to config DB (Also it can override in its own build_phase) in view of creating lower level UVM components. Is that correct?

Comment: Now it seems fine. Also, I would suggest you to grasp about uvm basics.